# Why does external I.P. need access to on-prem sql database when moving data with ADF to Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Why does external I.P. need access to on-prem sql database when copying data with ADF to Azure SQL?

It looks like on-prem sql makes a direct connection to Azure SQL (bypassing ADF). Is this by design or do I follow the wrong workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Factory use the integration runtime to help us create the connection to the Source/Sink dataset. Azure integration runtime for cloud dataset and Self-host integration runtime for on-premise source/sink dataset.

- The integration runtime (IR) is the compute infrastructure that Azure
  Data Factory uses to provide data-integration capabilities across
  different network environments. For details about IR, see Integration
  runtime overview.
- A self-hosted integration runtime can run copy activities between a
  cloud data store and a data store in a private network. It also can
  dispatch transform activities against compute resources in an
  on-premises network or an Azure virtual network. The installation of
  a self-hosted integration runtime needs an on-premises machine or a
  virtual machine inside a private network.

Azure integration runtime is provides by ADF in default. The self-host integration runtime must be created manually.

That means Data Factory can not access the on-prem SQL database directly. It need the [self-host integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to help us connect to the on-prem SQL database.

It means that the on-prem sql does not make a direct connection to Azure SQL(bypassing ADF. That why external I.P. need access to on-prem sql database when copying data with ADF to Azure SQL.

HTH.

Comment: Now do we have to create a firewall rule on azure sql db that includes the ip of self hosted IR ?

Comment: @Luukv93 Usually, you don't. If you have set the Azure SQL database firewall "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" to Yes.

Comment: Hi @Luukv93, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.